# SwiftUI: Translucent background for fullScreenCover

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So technically I want to show a loading screen view. I'm using `fullScreenCover`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isLoading = false
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello there")
            Button("Start loading") {
                isLoading.toggle()
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isLoading) {
                ZStack{
                    Color.black.opacity(0.5).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    VStack {
                        ProgressView()
                        Button("Stop loading") {
                            isLoading.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot make this loading screen translucent. `sheet` or `popover` behave the same way.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible way. Parameters of visual effect you can tune for your needs.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

```
       // ... other code
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isLoading) {
                ZStack{
                    Color.black.opacity(0.5).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    VStack {
                        ProgressView()
                        Button("Stop loading") {
                            isLoading.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(BackgroundBlurView())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BackgroundBlurView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            view.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I tried from 1 superview all the way to 4 superview (the window, after that superview is nil). what is the difference between using a custom view and simply using a translucent color for the background?

Comment: I take back what I said, it does show a blurred background. Thanks

Comment: do you know how to turn off the animation as well?

Comment: I tried a variant of this where the `superview?.backgroundColor` is updated synchronously. This didn't work, the value seemed to get overwritten. Does anyone know why? Specifically do you know when the superview's background color would get set?

Comment: This is not working for me. Do you guys have any other solution of this?

Comment: I ran into a race condition where this failed to work intermittently. Its possible for the async closure to execute before the view is added to the view hierarchy (at which point it doesn't ave a `superview.superview`. I added a recursive function that calls itself if `view.superview?.superview == nil` otherwise it sets these values. It seems to be working to cover this corner case.

Comment: Using this approach, I have 1 frame of white background randomly. Sometimes no flickering 10 times in a row, sometimes 1:1, sometimes several times in a row with flickering.

Answer (score 24):

Use [presentationBackground](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationbackground(_:)?changes=_8) to set desired background for modals (fullScreenCover, sheet, popover).  From the documentation:

> Allows views behind the presentation to show through translucent styles.

```
struct ContentView: View {
        
    @State private var isLoading = false
            
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello there")
            Button("Start loading") { isLoading.toggle() }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isLoading) {
                ZStack{
                    VStack {
                        ProgressView()
                        Button("Stop loading") { isLoading.toggle() }
                    }
                }
                .presentationBackground(.black.opacity(0.5))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Availability

```
@available(iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4, *)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, ignore everything else.

Comment: You cannot just "ignore everything else" if you need to support devices before iOS 16.4. And on this day there're still so many of these users out there

Answer (score 19):

Building on top of f3dm76 answer:

I changed it so content behind would not flicker (that happened to me with lazy images loading behind fullScreenCover). Also I wanted to use custom transitions for full screen content (or in some cases no animation at all), so I removed default animations with this approach as well.

```
extension View {

    func transparentNonAnimatingFullScreenCover<Content: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View {
        modifier(TransparentNonAnimatableFullScreenModifier(isPresented: isPresented, fullScreenContent: content))
    }
    
}

private struct TransparentNonAnimatableFullScreenModifier<FullScreenContent: View>: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let fullScreenContent: () -> (FullScreenContent)
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onChange(of: isPresented) { isPresented in
                UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented,
                             content: {
                ZStack {
                    fullScreenContent()
                }
                .background(FullScreenCoverBackgroundRemovalView())
                .onAppear {
                    if !UIView.areAnimationsEnabled {
                        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
                    }
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    if !UIView.areAnimationsEnabled {
                        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
                    }
                }
            })
    }
    
}

private struct FullScreenCoverBackgroundRemovalView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    private class BackgroundRemovalView: UIView {
        
        override func didMoveToWindow() {
            super.didMoveToWindow()
            
            superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return BackgroundRemovalView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for saving me ages on this flickering issue

Comment: I would love to see an example of how you did a custom transition with this, I can't seem to get that working

Comment: @ColinTremblay I have boolean variable in the view that needs to be presented full screen. It allows me to trigger animation / transition on that variable change. I change it in "onAppear" call.

Comment: Oh my Dear Lord, thank you!! That flickering was a PAIN

Comment: @Povilas could you show us an example?

Comment: Works perfect with simply .background(FullScreenCoverBackgroundRemovalView()), thanks, saved me a lot of time! But much simpler to remove animation with this .transaction { transaction in
                    transaction.disablesAnimations = false
                }, not editing globals.

Answer (score 15):

I found this cleaner solution for the flicker issue in the clear background.

```swift
struct ClearBackgroundView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return InnerView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    private class InnerView: UIView {
        override func didMoveToWindow() {
            super.didMoveToWindow()
            
            superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        
    }
}
```

Usage

```swift
PresenterView()
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
        PresentedView()
            .background(ClearBackgroundView())
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Update: please use Povilas's answer above to avoid flickering screen issue

Asperi's answer is beautiful, but in case you want background to be transparent and not blurred, here is how you can modify it. I also moved the code into a modifier for convenience. (xcode 13.3, iOS 15.4.1)

```
extension View {

    func transparentFullScreenCover<Content: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View {
        fullScreenCover(isPresented: isPresented) {
            ZStack {
                content()
            }
            .background(TransparentBackground())
        }
    }
}

struct TransparentBackground: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            view.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

Comment: It is causing default white background flickering. In 30-50% cases we have 1 frame of white background before background color will be set to.clear.

Comment: @bodich please see the answer from Povilas above this one

Comment: I have already used mix of both approaches. Background UIView from Povilas but simple to use .background(TransparentBackground()). My comment here just warns other devs from using your approach to save a lot of time on debugging "why the heck it's flickering" for hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct TransparentBackgroundView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var color: UIColor = .clear
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = _UIBackgroundBlurView()
        view.color = color
        return view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}

class _UIBackgroundBlurView: UIView {
    var color :UIColor = .clear
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PresenterView().fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
    PresentedView().background(TransparentBackgroundView())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the Material background type:

```
ZStack{
   ...
}
.background(.ultraThinMaterial)
```

See documentation for more usage:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/material