# Transparent and Blurred fullScreenCover modal in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm the fullScreenCover to show a modal in my SwiftUI project.

However, I need to show the modal with a transparent and blurred background.

But I can't seem to be able to achieve this at all.

This is my code:

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                       VStack(spacing: 20) {
                           Spacer()
                               .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100)
                               .background(Color.black)
                               .opacity(0.3)
                           
                           //Text("modal")
                       }
                       .background(SecondView())     // << helper !!
                   }
```

And I have this on the same View:

```
struct BackgroundBlurView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            view.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

The above code will open the fullscreen modal but its not transparent or blurred at all.

This is what I get:

[image]

is there something else I need to do?

***Reference to where I got the above code from:***

[SwiftUI: Translucent background for fullScreenCover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301041/swiftui-translucent-background-for-fullscreencover)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed some extraneous stuff and made sure that there was content in the background that you could see peeking through.

Without the `alpha` that is suggested in a different answer, the effect is **very** subtle, but there.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Some text")
            Spacer()
            Text("More")
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                isPresented.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Show fullscreenview")
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                Text("modal")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(BackgroundBlurView())
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("More text")
        }
        
    }
}

struct BackgroundBlurView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            view.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

[image: Note the extremely light blue you can see shining through]

Note the *extremely* subtle blue you can see from the `Button` shining through.  More obvious in dark mode.

[image]

The effect may get more dramatic as you add more color and content to the background view.  Adding `alpha` certainly makes things more obvious, though.

Answer (score 5):

@Asperi answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301041/swiftui-translucent-background-for-fullscreencover) is totally correct. Just need to add alpha to blur view.

```
struct BackgroundBlurView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        view.alpha = 0.5 //< --- here
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            view.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

---

Another approach is to use ViewControllerHolder [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56756318/14733292)

```
struct ViewControllerHolder {
    weak var value: UIViewController?
}

struct ViewControllerKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: ViewControllerHolder {
        return ViewControllerHolder(value: UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController)
    }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var viewController: UIViewController? {
        get { return self[ViewControllerKey.self].value }
        set { self[ViewControllerKey.self].value = newValue }
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    func present<Content: View>(backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear, @ViewBuilder builder: () -> Content) {
        let toPresent = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))
        toPresent.view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        toPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        toPresent.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
        toPresent.rootView = AnyView(
            builder()
                .environment(\.viewController, toPresent)
        )
        
        //Add blur efect
        let blurEfect = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))
        blurEfect.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        blurEfect.alpha = 0.5
        toPresent.view.insertSubview(blurEfect, at: 0)
        self.present(toPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentViewNeo: View {
    @Environment(\.viewController) private var viewControllerHolder: UIViewController?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Background screen")
            Button("Open") {
                viewControllerHolder?.present(builder: {
                    SheetView()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Sheet view")
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```