# SwiftUI: fullScreenCover with no animation?

Tags: swiftui

I have this view:

```
struct TheFullCover: View {
    
    @State var showModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        Button(action: {
            showModal.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Modal")
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            
        }
        .background(Color(.white))
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(.red, lineWidth:1)
        )
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showModal, onDismiss: {
            
        }, content: {
            VStack {
                Text("Here I am")
                TheFullCover()
            }
        })
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Every time I press the Button, the modal screen comes up fullscreen. All works great.

Question:

How do I disable the slide up animation? I want the view to be presented immediately fullscreen without animating to it.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't think you can disable the system animation of `fullScreenCover` (unless maybe the user has an accessibility option for reduced motion on). I'd probably just use a `ZStack` and present the view on top without animation.

Comment: @zumzum this should be a answer! https://stackoverflow.com/a/72973172/1823922

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A possible solution is to disable views animation completely (and then, if needed, enable again in `.onAppear` of presenting content), like

```
    Button(action: {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)    // << here !!
        showModal.toggle()
    }) {
```

and then

```
    }, content: {
        VStack {
            Text("Here I am")
            TheFullCover()
        }
        .onAppear {
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)    // << here !!
        }
    })
```

Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15

Comment: Works great with Xcode 13.3 and MacOS 12.3 (running on M1)!

Comment: This work for me . its save my time

Answer (score 30):

AFAIK the proper to do it as of today is using `transaction` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/transaction

```
var transaction = Transaction()
transaction.disablesAnimations = true
withTransaction(transaction) {
   showModal.toggle()
}
```

I also created a handy extension for this:

```
extension View {
    func withoutAnimation(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        var transaction = Transaction()
        transaction.disablesAnimations = true
        withTransaction(transaction) {
            action()
        }
    }
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
withoutAnimation {
    // do your thing
}
```

Comment: @zumzum This is the most elegant way to and this should be an answer to this question! Its works iOS 16/17

Answer (score 16):

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: isPresented) {
    content()
        .background(TransparentBackground())
}
.transaction({ transaction in
    transaction.disablesAnimations = true
})
```

this should work, based on [@asamoylenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72973172/8041103)

Comment: But what about TransparentBackground? Can you share the code to reproduce your answer?

Comment: @bodich could be something like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/72124662/6669289

Comment: Thanks @HossamSherif! Looks the same as I did it))

Comment: This disables also push animations for navigation links

Answer (score 6):

At the moment, I find it easier to use UIKit for presentation in SwiftUI.

```
someView
  .onChange(of: isPresented) { _ in
    if isPresented {
      let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: MyView())
      vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
      UIApplication.shared.rootVC?.present(vc, animated: false)
    } else {
      UIApplication.shared.rootVC?.dismiss(animated: false)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I like this approach. Not saying it's by the book or anything, but considering SwiftUI still has a long way to go to be production ready for real, this seems like a valid option. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can disable animations when presenting or dismissing a `View` by wrapping the state / binding mutation in [`withTransaction(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/withtransaction(_:_:)) and setting the `transaction`'s `disablesAnimations` property to `true`.

The following Swift 5.9 / iOS 17 example shows a possible implementation to disable animations when a `View` is presented with `fullScreenCover` or dismissed:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresentingFullScreenView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Button("Present (with animation)") {
                    isPresentingFullScreenView = true
                }
                Button("Present (no animation)") {
                    var transaction = Transaction()
                    transaction.disablesAnimations = true
                    withTransaction(transaction) {
                        isPresentingFullScreenView = true
                    }
                }
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentingFullScreenView) {
                FullScreenView(isPresentingFullScreenView: $isPresentingFullScreenView)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Content view")
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FullScreenView: View {
    @Binding var isPresentingFullScreenView: Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Button("Dismiss (with animation)") {
                    isPresentingFullScreenView = false
                }
                Button("Dismiss (no animation)") {
                    var transaction = Transaction()
                    transaction.disablesAnimations = true
                    withTransaction(transaction) {
                        isPresentingFullScreenView = false
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Full screen view")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not use an overlay instead?

```
.overlay {
        if isLoading {
            ZStack {
                ProgressView()
            }
            .background(BackgroundCleanerView())
        }
    }
```

Comment: how will overlay cover full screen including tabs with proper animation ?

Comment: place the overlay at the root most view? what do you mean with proper animation? didnt the OP say full screen cover with no animation?

Comment: if the tabview has more children of navigation then we may have to add all of the children popups to root. For example if I'm showing tooltips on 20 internal views then i'll have to pass bindings from root ?

Comment: ok. i guess since i only have 1 popup for 1 tab out fo 3 it worked for me.