# SwiftUI: FullScreenCover background color during orientation change animation

Tags: ios, swiftui, fullscreen

When using a `.fullScreenCover()` ViewModifier and setting its background, that background is not respected during the orientation change animation.

**How can I get rid of the white background during orientation change?**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .background(Color.black.ignoresSafeArea())
        }
        .background(Color.red.ignoresSafeArea())
    }
}
```

In this specific case it shows (partially) a white background during view resizing (open the gif in a separate window):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64301261/20407691).

You need to get hold of the underlying UIKit View and change its background color to `.clear` (it seems to be `.white` as default, which would be nice if Apple could change it):

```
struct BackgroundClearView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            view.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
            view.superview?.superview?.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        }
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

and then apply it to your SwiftUI View:

```
.background(BackgroundTransparentView())
```

Comment: While this probably works you should use it with a caution - it is not granted that view hierarchy will not change with the iOS update and as such this may lead to various problems in the future.